# Send Bitmap using data URI scheme

Tags: android

I'm trying another approach for this problem: [Share image without WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222614/share-image-without-write-external-storage)

My idea is to encode a PNG in the [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). My code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
baos.write("data:image/png;base64,".getBytes());
Base64OutputStream base64 = new Base64OutputStream(baos, Base64.NO_WRAP);
boolean ok = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, base64);
base64.close();
if (ok) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(baos.toString());
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/png");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The applications I've tried (e.g. Gmail on Android 4.4.4) say they cannot open the image.
Do I create my `Uri` correctly? If so, what prevents other applications from reading my image?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Do I create my Uri correctly?

I have no idea.

> If so, what prevents other applications from reading my image?

Because they have no idea what to do with a `data` `Uri`.