# share app screenshot without WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Tags: android

Is it possible to share own app screenshots without adding any permissions ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And this is my others apps code which is works on copy to cache and share

```
public void sendFile(File paramFile) {

        String fileExtension = ".apk";
        File temporaryFile;
        try {
            temporaryFile = File.createTempFile(paramFile.getName(), fileExtension, getApplicationContext().getExternalCacheDir());
            copy(paramFile, temporaryFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            temporaryFile = paramFile;
        }
        Intent localIntent = new Intent();
        localIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.SEND");
        localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", Uri.fromFile(temporaryFile));
        localIntent.setType("application/*");
        localIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(localIntent, ""));
    }
```

Comment: definitely not. how could you share the file without  read it.

Comment: some thing write to cache and then share?

Comment: Give a try. Definitely not.

Comment: is it a best practice for sharing to save it somewhere and share?

Comment: How can you? Are you going save the cache in system chip memory. You are writing the application in android os . right? so you need to create the file as cache file and save it in temporary location. that location also will be in phone storage or external card. then, how can you?

Comment: I have an app, and in this app , I copying file to cache and share, without any permissions ,and it really works.

Comment: Could you post your code. We will see what you have done. ?

Comment: Posted in questions  @Ahamed

Comment: but it don't exists in manifest and google play store, I need something like this. And also it works without it also

Comment: you can not share file directly, as you have to set URI as share in intent chooser.

Comment: Check this answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29231467/7479343

Answer (score 3):

Save your image to internal storage (e.g., `getCacheDir()`), then [use `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to make it available to other apps. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html) for more.

Comment: @seyxsultan: Both documentation links that I have in my answer contain sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using getExternalCacheDir()

it absolute the path to youraplication specific directory on the primary
   external storage device where the application can place cache
   files it owns. These files are internal to the application, and not
   typically visible to the user as media.

There is no security enforced with these files. 
no need to add the permissions to read or write to the returned path. it's always accessible to the youraplication app. This only applies to paths generated for package name of the youraplication.

```
android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE 
android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```