# Issue while sharing image with viber

Tags: android, android-intent

I have facing one issue while sharing the content from my app using android intent. The content that I'm sharing is present in app's private memory.

I'm using **FileProvider** for sharing and am able to share it on some of the app (like : Twitter, Gmail, Whatsapp). But however for some reason when I'm selecting the Viber from App chooser, it is showing a blank screen.

If I change the content location to **external SD card**, then it is working fine even for **Viber** also.

My problem is that if I change the content location to sd card then I have to use the **WRITE_STORAGE_PERMISSION**, which I don't want.

Please help on how this can be done for Viber, without moving the content and without using any extra permission as it is possible to share on other apps.

**Code for sharing intent**

```
    Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "packagemane.pdffilesprovider", newFile);
        shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        shareIntent.setType("*/*");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content +"\n"+url);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
```

**FileProvider in manifest**

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="cpackagemane.pdffilesprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/fileprovider" />
    </provider>
```

**fileprovider.xml file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
          <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
          <files-path name="my_images" path="images/"/>
    </paths>
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @Divers please have a look, I have added the code

Comment: Seems like that answer should help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40613643/how-to-share-image-to-viber-app-via-file-provider

Comment: @Divers Thanks for the suggestion, I tried to use it but doesn't help. Also I tried to the demo app from **commonsware** and in demo app also I'm not able to share using viber.