# action.SEND intent-filter doesn't work in android API 26(Oreo)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-8.0-oreo

1. Usage Scenario : 
   I'd like to have My app's users to able to share My app's image screenshot contents **to My own app's specific activity(Community page)** as well as other SNS-like apps(facebook, instagram, whatsapp, etc). Which means, **My app icon should be shown in Sharevia app list** as well when a user click 'share' button in My app.
2. Problem : ***In Android API 26(Oreo OS)***, My app icon is ***NOT*** shown in Sharevia app list when a user click 'share' button. In contrast, in API 25 N OS, it is working fine. (I've tested Google android reference device, Pixel.)
3. Codes:

   ```
   private static void showShareViaDialog(final Context context, ArrayList<Uri> shareFileUris) {
   if (context == null || shareFileUris == null) {
       LOG.e(TAG, "Either context or Uri list object is null");
       ToastView.makeCustomView(ContextHolder.getContext(), R.string.share_image_storage_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       return;
   }

   Intent sendingIntent;
   Intent chooserActivity;
   if (shareFileUris.size() <= 0) {
       LOG.e(TAG, "Uri list is empty");
       return;

   if (shareFileUris.size() == 1) {
       LOG.d(TAG, " showShareViaDialog() : only one file is about to share ");
       sendingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       sendingIntent.setType("image/png");
       sendingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, shareFileUris.get(0));
       sendingIntent.putExtra(THEME_CHOOSER, THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT);
       sendingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
       chooserActivity = Intent.createChooser(sendingIntent, context.getResources().getText(R.string.share_via));

   if (chooserActivity != null) {
       LOG.d(TAG, " showShareViaDialog() : chooser activity is " + chooserActivity.getClass());
       chooserActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
       LockManager.getInstance().registerIgnoreActivity(context.getClass());
       List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(chooserActivity,
           PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
       for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfoList) {
           String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
           context.grantUriPermission(packageName, shareFileUris.get(0), Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

       }
       LOG.d(TAG, " showShareViaDialog() : chooser activity is starting " + chooserActivity.getClass());
       context.startActivity(chooserActivity);
   }
   ```

Intent sending partial code

---

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/png" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Intent-filter in AndroidManifest.xml

At first, I just thought it has something to do with [Android Oreo Broadcast Limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts). However, action.SEND is activity Intent, not broadcast Intent. And I found some opposite case question of mine, [Why is my ACTION_SEND working on API 25+ perfectly, but messes up on previous APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736968/why-is-my-action-send-working-on-api-25-perfectly-but-messes-up-on-previous-ap). It's intriguing.

Why is this flow job not working in API 26? Is there more something to do to receive action.SEND Intent in API 26?

---

++more information,

> shareFileUris.get(0). We have no idea what you try to share. Please
>   give the value of Uri.toString(). – greenapps 14 mins ago

It's an uri that indicate an PNG type Image file. Please refer below codes.

```
                    Uri shareUri;
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > ANDROID_BUILD_VERSION_LOLLIPOP) {
                    shareUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(SHARE_VIA_AUTHORITY, file);
                    LOG.d(TAG, " doInBackground(): share Uri through FileProvider  " + shareUri.toString());

                } else {
                    shareUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    LOG.d(TAG, " doInBackground(): share Uri through Uri apis  " + shareUri.toString());

                }
                //  context.grantUriPermission();
                //                   Uri shareUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                shareUris = new ArrayList<>();
                shareUris.add(shareUri);

        public static Uri getUriForFile(String authority, File file) {
        return Uri.parse("content://" + authority + "/" + file.getName());
    }
```

Comment: `this flow currently doesn't work. `. Pretty bad bad problem description. Better tell how it flows instead. Tell exactly what works and what not.

Comment: `shareFileUris.get(0)`. We have no idea what you try to share. Please give the value of Uri.toString().

Comment: `well as other SNS-like apps`. ???

Comment: Have you tried already `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)` to build your share intent?

Comment: okay, I got it. I edited to more clarify instead "this flow currently doesn't work. ".

Comment: greenapps - "well as other SNS-like apps. ???" =>
facekbook, instagram, whatsapp, etc,, anything apps that able to get PNG image file.

Comment: "Have you tried already ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity) to build your share intent? – donfuxx" => No I didn't yet. Is that necessary? I'll try that right away.

Comment: "shareFileUris.get(0). We have no idea what you try to share. Please give the value of Uri.toString(). – greenapps 40 mins ago"

=> I've updated in question. Please check that.

Comment: Have you tried already ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity) to build your share intent? – donfuxx => It didn't work.. still not showing My app in share app list:(

Comment: I have faced similar problem, but does not get any solution